# Life cycle of props with state in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I couldn't find any clear information or video about when the props are received in the react component life-cycle. Let's make an example:

```
export const App = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    
    console.log(A, count)

    return (
        <Component count={count} justText={'hello'} onClick={() => setState(state => state + 1)}/>
    );
}

const Component = ({count, justText}) => {
    const [count2, setCount2]=useState(0)

    console.log("B ",count)
    console.log("C ",justText)
    console.log("D",count2)

    useEffect(()=> {
        console.log("F", count)
        console.log("G",count2)
    });

    return (
        <>
            {console.log(E,count)}
        </>
    )
}
```

I would like to know the execution order and why is that, because sometimes I found that when passing props with state down, the component which received them gets `undefined` but in the component where it is declared it is already initialized. Sometimes I need to wait the useEffect to get the value, so I am lost in what happens with the props during the lifecycle when mounting, and updating. I tried to find information about it but couldn't see anywhere where they explain the props lifecycle.
Thank you!

PD: Just setted random values for A,B,C...they don't follow any order.

Comment: Please have the decency to post reasonably formatted and valid code. The one you posted was barely readable and riddled with syntax errors. Unless those syntax errors are your question, try to do better.

Answer (score 0):

You won't get undefined while console logging the props in the function or console logging the state :

```
import React from "react";

function Component() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(false);
  console.log(state);
  return <Other state={state}></Other>;
}

export default Component;
```

```
import React from "react";

function Other({ state }) {
  console.log(state);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(state);
  }, []);
  return <div>Other component</div>;
}

export default Other;
```

React components gets states and props before mounting so they will never be undefined when you want to use them .

Comment: But in case of states, that is asynchronous so they May not have received the value initialized yet maybe?

Comment: @pepinillo6969 You will always get the initial value of the state or prop . If the value of state get's changed the component will re-render and the console log will be a new value

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I can't vote yet. If you vote the question I think I will be able.

Comment: Yes but both are valid, and well explained can't choose one sorry.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**

Lifecycle of a props starts when it gets mount and stays until it gets called or re-rendered by the parent that is using it. When it re-rendered by the parent it gets the props again but it can be unchanged or changed.

**Full story**

The lifecycle of a props is very straight forward. When your component is being called from a Parent it's props is also passed at that time. Think props as the function parameter. Suppose you have a function like below

```
const fn = (param1, param2) => {
    // your function implementation
}
```

Here when you call the function you call it with the params like this

```
fn(val1, val2)
```

So each time you call the function you pass the params. If any time calling the function any of the param is not passed it will get `null`

A component and it's props is also same. Here the Component is the function and the props are the params. Every time the components gets called or rendered it is called or rendered with the props.

Now, If your parent that is using the component, pass all the props then the component will get the value. But if it doesn't pass all the props it will get null.

Like function you can also define the initial value of a props like this

```
const Component1 = ({props1='val1', props2='val2', ...rest}) => {
    return()
}
```

In the code above even if you do not pass `props1 and props2` from the parent. Still it will not be null, it will have the initial value.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I can't vote yet. If you vote the question I think I will be able.